# Медленный запрос

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

**Индексы стоят**, но почему-то данный запрос загружается медленно(1 млн записей в базе):

```
SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from WHERE (notifications.type = 3 OR notifications.type = 17) AND notifications.modules = 3 AND notifications.eid = $id ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: С помощью EXPLAIN смотрели запрос? В любом случае для ответа на Ваш вопрос нужна схема БД.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, план выполнения надо смотреть, скорее всего берется не тот индекс какой нужно, либо нужного индекса просто нет. Также надо смотреть количество возвращаемых записей (в абсолютном и относительном соотношении) всем запросом целиком, а также частями - сколько записей возвращается после каждого условия.

Если у вас применяется индекс по type и в результате возвращается 900к записей из миллиона, то смысла в использовании такого индекса в данном запросе нет.

В запросах с большим количеством условий необходимо максимально сократить количество записей возвращаемых при использовании индекса. Например, если юзер у вас наплодил 10-100 записей всего (среди миллиона прочих записей других юзеров), то индексы для других полей смысла использовать нет. 100 записей субд вполне способна быстро пробежать и отфильтровать по типам и т.д. Аналогично для других полей - если можно получить короткую выборку после индекса, значит нужно использовать такой индекс.

Конечно, не всегда возможно выбрать индекс по одному полю так, чтобы получить сразу короткий набор. Тогда надо использовать составной индекс по нескольким полям. Опять же по каким полям такой индекс должен быть - определять надо исходя из количества записей, которые вернутся после поиска по этому индексу.

Увлекаться составными индексами не стоит (например сделать индекс на все поля), из-за размера индекса его польза будет ничтожной по сравнению с обычным fullscan'ом а то и станет хуже, при этом размер базы вырастет.

Какой индекс использовать выбирает субд, но всегда есть возможность в запросе указать какой использовать индекс принудительно (см. в [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html)).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а вот я поставил на все поля индексы и сайт стал летать. Я грешный?

Comment: он будет летать на выборках, если добавить много **правильных** индексов. Но на вставках может прилечь сильно:) Пока для миллиона записей индексы перестроишь...

Comment: :) Нет, грех если и есть, то небольшой. Вы создали на каждое поле по индексу, так? Ну это просто означает, что большая часть индексов у вас просто не работает, но субд сама подбирает (раз все летает, значит удачно подбирает) индекс из них для ваших запросов. Вот если бы вы создали составной индекс один на все поля, то тут скорее всего было бы только хуже.

Comment: Оптимизацией производительности запросов занимаются специальные люди - DBA, которые в общем-то могут быть далеки от предметной области. Рассматривают определенный запрос и исследуют его производительность, варьируют индексы и проч. То, что для вас кажется непонятным - это нормально, тут дело практики и понимания работы субд, со временем придет...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, но вот проблема в том, что я не знаю, как ускорить запрос выше :( всё летает кроме него. А именно вот таких двойных запросов.

Comment: Значит нужен составной индекс какой-то. Ваших данных я не вижу, какой именно индекс нужен, не знаю. Экспериментируйте.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, не совсем понял. Какой из них составной индекс http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1358758427-clip-3kb.png или это не то?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,  Первичный  Уникальный  Индекс  Пространственный  Полнотекстовый. Какой? Если просто индекс, то он стоит на всех полях..

Comment: "Индекс". Вы поставили по индексу на каждое поле - это не то же что один индекс на несколько полей.  
**N.B.** Галочками отмечаете поля, которые должны в индекс входить и жмете внизу, под структурой Индекс.  
При этом скорее всего вам **потребуется** использовать хинты, т.к. mysql предпочитает использовать индексы на одно поле, а не по нескольким. Ссылку на документацию по хинтам я дал в ответе.

Comment: Отключились комментарии, поэтому тут. @Yura Ivanov, выполнил explain и показало: http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1358765485-clip-11kb.png Как понять это?

Comment: Это значит, что применился индекс по полю from. Отфильтровано 658 записей.  Хороший в принципе индекс.   
Только у вас в запросе фильтр идет не по from, по from вы соединяетесь с users. Вам надо смотреть условия по type, eid и modules...

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте наоборот:

```
SELECT * FROM users u JOIN notifications n ON u.vk_id = n.from WHERE n.type in (3,17) AND n.modules = 3 AND n.eid = $id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: @KaZaца, неа. всё равно...